# Why are back edges required in the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, ford-fulkerson

To find the maximum flow in a graph, why doesn't it suffice to only saturate all augmenting paths with the minimum edge capacity in that path without considering the back edges? I mean, what is the point calling it a back edge if we assume flow from it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Back edges are necessary when doing the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm in case the path that you choose ends up not being a part of the overall flow.

As an example where back edges are necessary, consider this flow network:

```
    s
   / \
  a   b
   \ / \
    c   d
     \ /
      t
```

Assume that all edges point down and that all edges have capacity 1 and that you want to find a flow from s to t. Suppose on the first iteration of Ford-Fulkerson that you take the path s → b → c → t. At this point, you've pushed one unit of flow from s to t. If you don't add in any back edges, you're left with this:

```
    s
   / 
  a   b
   \   \
    c   d
       /
      t
```

There are no more s-t paths, but that doesn't mean you have a max flow. You can push two units of flow from s to t by sending one along the path s → a → c → t and the other along the path s → b → d → t. Without any back edges in the residual flow network, you would never discover this other path.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please go into more detail as to what would make up the backedges in your specific case? Thank you!

Comment: @bluejamesbond Here, the back edges would point from b to s, from c to b, and from t to c (it's the reverse of the edges that were along the path taken). Those edges then give an augmenting path from s to t that  shows that the flow isn't maximum.

Comment: When will it take those paths however?

Comment: Which paths are you referring to?

Comment: The residual edges you added are now in the graph. But, how will the next iteration of FordF using BFS/DFS take that into consideration because there is no path between S and T even if there is a back edge. Update: I see it now, being an idiot there. My bad!

Comment: I have a basic question , if the above graph is directed , after adding back ekdge ..second flow would be s->a->c -> b -> d ->t  of capacity 1, so max flow is 2 , which is fine ... but if compared to real life example of pipe connecting their is no pipe between c->b , so how does it work ?

Comment: Amazing how a simple example can clarify the entire algorithm.

Comment: This was the best example I've ever found which clarifies the logic behind back edges in the residual graph.

Comment: @LalitaKumar I am late, but for future readers, that means the amount of flow in back edge(c->b) never happened in (b->c), i.e, in this example it would mean there never was any flow in b->c.